# Back Button Webview Problem (Delayed work after few clicks)

Tags: java, android

I made a back button for my webview, but I got a problem.
When I click it more time (for example 5/6) it's back to the main page, but later button work like on delay, so I'm on some page and my app goes back. It's possible to limit the click of the button to only 1 click per page?

Thanks.

```
Button przycisk_powrot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.przycisk_powrot);
        przycisk_powrot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the button state to enabled/disabled - and can make a check like this:

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if (webView.canGoBack()) {
         webView.goBack();
// Now check is it still can go back, ?
           backButton.setEnabled(webView.canGoBack());
           backButton.setAlpha((float)1.0);
     }
     else {
           backButton.setEnabled(false);
// Also make the button little dim, so will show to user that it is currently in disabled state
           backButton.setAlpha((float)0.5);
     }
}
});
```

Enjoy..!

Comment: Thanks, but i need to show button again when previous page is loaded. Like i click back button (gone) and when previous page is loaded show button again (like 1 back click on loaded page)

Comment: Then for this handle the functionality of back button in Previous page.

Comment: Can you help me with code in this? I'm new in java ;(

Comment: Sure, I'll try my best.. share your logic/code.

Comment: Thanks! here is my all MainActivity with added your code https://codeshare.io/aJL8e6

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    myWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```